# The number of bits in $N!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I'm struggling with this homework problem:

If $N$ is an $n$-bit number, how many bits long is $N!$ approximately (in $Θ(·)$ form)?

I know that the number of bits in $N$ is equivalent to log base $2$ of $N$, but that's about it. Any hints on where to start?

Comment: Have you heard of Stirling Formula?

Comment: Strictly speaking the number of bits in a binary representation of positive integer $N$ is $\lfloor log_2 N \rfloor + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Stirling, can you show that $\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} < n! < n^n$? Then take logs.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2(n!)=\log_2[n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 1]=\log_2 n+\log_2(n-1)+\cdots+\log_2 1$$
There are $n$ terms, and most of the terms are close to $\log_2 n$ in magnitude. Therefore $\log_2(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

(To prove this more formally, use Stirling's approximation.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Stirling's approximation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the way I meant to solve this problem, there's no mention of that in my text book. Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: You can read the derivation of the formula, but it's not that easy to figure out.